# Ignoring Listcontrol 'DELETE_ALL_ITEMS' Event when closing application

Tags: c++, mfc, event-handling, listcontrol

I have a MFC ListControl in my application.  I have an event that occurs when "all items in the view were deleted".  The event throws an error message and then closes the program.

**My problem is that the event also gets called if the <kbd>X</kbd>(close) button is clicked.**

Here is my code for the LVN_DeleteAllItems event:

```
void Users::OnLvnDeleteallitemsList1(NMHDR *pNMHDR, LRESULT *pResult)
{
    LPNMLISTVIEW pNMLV = reinterpret_cast<LPNMLISTVIEW>(pNMHDR);
    MessageBox("The SQL connection has been dropped.  Please restart the application.","SQL Connection Error",MB_ICONSTOP);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    *pResult = 0;
}
```

Is there a way to keep the event from being called if the application is closed correctly (with the button in the top right corner)?

Comment: Why are you calling `exit`? Once that message box closes the application will immediately exit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the normal behavior. When the X button gets pressed, the main window receives a WM_CLOSE, and start to call its children destructors. When the ListView destructor is called all its item are cleaned up, so there goes your  `LVN_DeleteAllItems` notification.

The (logical) error is that the connection to the DB being dropped test is being performed here (and also the abnormal `exit` procedure).  Here only ListView additional tasks should be performed.  The database connection check should be handled higher in the callstack: a good example is the place in the code that sent the `LVM_DeleteAllItems` (note the LV**M**_DeleteAllItems), and triggered the ListView to be emptied.

Comment: If it's a dialog box then override `ON_WM_DESTROY()`

Comment: I don't think that'll do it. Somewhere in your code there's a place (other than the `CDialog` destructor or `WM_DESTROY` message handler; it could be the place that instructs the `CDialog` to close/destroy) that signals the `ListView` to delete all its items. Instead clearing the `ListView`'s items it should display the `Connection dropped` `MessageBox` and signal the CDialog to close. Also the `MessageBox` and `exit` should be removed from `OnLvnDeleteallitemsList1`.

Comment: Thanks @CristiFati.  I found what was causing my program to empty the set.  I then moved the error message and `exit` before that.